# Local JQuery and JQuery mobile files not working on localhost

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to my assignment which needs me to use JQuery and JQuery Mobile.

I'm using nginx so my PC acts as a webserver.

When I try to view the html on Chrome, the "data-role" property doesn't work for some reason.

If i use the CDN hosted JQuery, then it works. but not my local JQuery files which is strange. I've used different versions as well.

Furthermore, my console doesn't show me any errors.

Below is the code to how I'm linking the JQuery files.

and this is the output I'm getting

[image: out put]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Chicken Logger</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ChickenLogs.css">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src=js/jquery.mobile.min.js></script>

</head>
<body>
<div data-role="header">

  <h3> Chicken Logger </h3>

</div>
    ...content goes here
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't it work?

UPDATE 1:

My university gave us 3 different jquery files named "jquery.js", "jquery.mobile.js" and "jquery.css". I've put these in my js folder and when I link them, they don't work. But if I take them out of the js folder and put them in the root folder, they work.

So I'm just thinking my relative path is wrong?

I've seen some other similar questions but none of them have worked for me too.

UPDATE 2:

[image: folder structer]

Comment: can you check the source code and then try to view your jquery. Just tell is it working

Comment: See update in my post

Comment: So that mean you have to set the path correctly. If you can update the snap of your folder structure so that we can provide a better answer

Comment: try adding a `/` at the beginning of the path like: `<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @NipunTharuksha added snap of project folder

Comment: @Shuvo I tried that as well and it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some odd reason it's working now with the posted code.

Worth to mention that if you're using xginx and if you specify your relative path starting with a / for example /js/jquery.js, then the server (localhost) will look for the file in localhost/js/jquery.js and not in localhost/project_folder/js/jquery.js which is very strange

Comment: I think if you add `<base>` in your head, then it will help to solve your this kind of problem, like: `<base href="folder_name/"> `

Comment: I guess but it's working now anyway so there's no way to check. But thanks!